# How to make a frame with border in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to make a frame for a density plot. I start with

```
set terminal pngcairo size 400,400 enhanced
set output 'test.png'

set view map
unset tics
unset colorbox
set size ratio 1

set border 15 front lw 20
#set border 15 back lw 20

splot sin(sqrt(x**2+y**2))/sqrt(x**2+y**2) w pm3d notitle
```

[image]

If I use `front` the border looks continuous, but it eats a portion of the plot. If I use `back`, it no longer looks like a frame.

How can I make a proper frame such that it stays out of the plot region?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `square` option for the line endings of the `pngcairo` terminal might help:

```
set terminal pngcairo size 400,400 enhanced square
set output 'test.png'

set view map
unset tics
unset colorbox
set size ratio 1

set border 15 back lw 20

splot sin(sqrt(x**2+y**2))/sqrt(x**2+y**2) w pm3d notitle
```

This produces:

[image]

One might also want to slightly increase the `isosamples`, e.g., `set isosamples 100` to get a smoother plot:

[image]